# n-dimensional Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm going over the book by Rene L. Schilling "Measures, integrals, and Martingales". There's a part where he proves that the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.
[image]

Schilling says it is clear that $\mathcal A_x$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. However, to me it is not. I can't seem to prove that if $A \in \mathcal A_x$, so is $A^c$. That is, why is $A^c+x \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: $A^{c}+x=(A+x)^{c}$

Comment: I thought about it. But how do you show that formally?

Comment: If $y\in (A+x)^c$, then $y$ does not have the form $a+x$, where $a\in A$ and thus, $y-x$ is not an element of $A$. Definitionally, this means that $y\in A^c+x$. The other inclusion is similar.

Comment: Thanks Woolier Than Thouh :)